# JSONObject Unit Testing Always Null

Tags: android, json

I have been looking at this for an hour and can't seem to see what's wrong.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
jsonResponse.put("JSON", "hi");
String myString = jsonResponse.getString("JSON");
assertEquals("hi", myString);
```

Result... (The entire method throws Throwable). I tried try/catch as well. Same result....

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :hi
Actual   :null
```

This is the class I am using

```
public class ECUserTests(){

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testUserExists(){

        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
            jsonResponse.put("JSON", "Hello, World!");
            String myString = jsonResponse.getString("JSON");
            assertEquals("hi", myString);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post code for a minimal program that can be run? I dropped the above into a Java class and ran it successfully. (My only modification was changing assertEquals to Assert.assertEquals.)

Comment: Just added it. Thanks

Comment: The answer for your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35675861/3032209

Answer (score 9):

I suppose you're running the unit test outside of Android and compiling against `android.jar`. This lib contains only class and interface signatures without any implementation.

**Solution:**

Either execute the unit test in Android context (not on PC) or when running on PC, you have to load the "real" JSON library into your test.

Comment: How do I load the "real" JSON library into a test?

Comment: What do you use? Gradle, Maven, ...? In Gradle and Maven you can define a compile/test dependency to org.json.

Comment: Thanks. I use gradle and after adding "testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'" to build.gradle I can now use JSONObjects in tests.