# UnitTest JSONObject shows null

Tags: android, json, unit-testing

I have got a problem connected with JSONObject.

```
@Test
public void toUrlTest() throws JSONException {
    String url;

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put"id", 1);
    json.put("email", "test@hotmail.com");
    url = JSONParser.toURLString(json);

    assertEquals("id=1&email=test@hotmail.com", url);

}
```

The problem is when I am debugging this test, it shows that nothing is put to json object.

> json={org.json.JSONObject@826} "null"

I checked everything and I got no clue why this happen. JSONObject works fine in app. It only happens while testing.

PS.
I have added in build.gradle this

```
 testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }
```

Comment: Where are you running the tests? On PC or on device/simulator?

Comment: I use pc I guess, becouse there is no screen to choose device

Comment: Such tests don't work on PC with android.jar. `android.jar` contains only signatures of classes, not the implementation. Run the tests on device.

Comment: Are there any additional settings in build.gradle required? Have you got some tips on how to do this? I am new in android

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR version of Yair Kukielka's response... (thanks!)

Add this to your `build.gradle` file, as suggested by

```
testImplementation "org.json:json:20140107"
```

This will replace the stubbed Android library with one that works on the desktop.

*Edit April '22*: Comments suggest that this is the latest version:

```
testImplementation "org.json:json:20180813"
```

Comment: nice and simple solution

Comment: Thanks! I expected things in the "android" package to be stubbed but I did not expect `org.json.JSONObject` to be stubbed! Also, `org.json:json:20180813` appears to be the latest version as of 2022.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 types of unit tests in Android:

- **Instrumented** (slow and you need a device or emulator)
- **Non-instrumented or local** (fast and you can execute them on the JVM on your computer)

If your unit tests use classes provided by the Android SDK (like the JSONObject or a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)), you'll have to choose between:

- making your test an instrumented test

*OR*

- use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)

You have more useful info about this subject in [this](https://medium.com/@yair.kukielka/android-unit-tests-explained-219b04dc55b5#.1r4eqwfcb) post.

By the way, in the post you'll learn a trick to convert your JSONObject unit test to a non-instrumented test that you can execute on your local JVM (without Roboelectric)

Comment: Post was great to use json with local JVM just for testing purposes!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mockito to mock JSONObject and return the JSON object you need.

Example:

```
@Test  
public void myTest(){

      JsonHttpResponseHandler handler = myClassUnderTest.getHandlerForGetCalendar(testFuture);
      JSONObject successResp = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
      JSONArray events = Mockito.mock(JSONArray.class);
      JSONObject event = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);

  try{
    doReturn("Standup meeting with team..")
    .when(event).getString("Subject");

    doReturn("id_")
    .when(event).getString("Id");

    doReturn(1)
    .when(events).length();

    doReturn(event)
    .when(events).getJSONObject(0);

    doReturn(events)
    .when(successResp).getJSONArray("value");

    handler.onSuccess(200, null, successResp);

  }catch(Exception xx){
    JSONObject errorResp = null;
    try{
      errorResp = new JSONObject("{}"); // this will be null but it's fine for the error case..
    }catch(JSONException ex){
      throw new IllegalStateException("Test Exception during json error response construction. Cause: "+ex);
    }
    handler.onFailure(500, null, new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong in test helper handlerForGetCalendarOnSuccess. Cause: "+xx), errorResp);
  }

  // Assertions you need ..
```

}