# How to mock JSONObject?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking

In the middle of a method I'm doing something like this

```
JSONObject = new JSONObject(json);
```

Now I'm trying to unit test that using `Android Studio` and `JUnit`. Unfortunately, Android Studio won't let me create a real `JSONObject` instance and ask me to mock it.

What's the simplest way to keep that code and being able to unit test?

`Mockito` won't help me since it's not able to mock constructors, but it seems `PowerMock` is the way to go.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35675861/3032209

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've finally used [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/). It allows you to run tests simulating real device conditions. This makes unnecessary to mock frameworks classes.

Just need to add `robolectric` reference to gradle and decorate my test classes with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`

Comment: Thanks! `testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.1'` gradle example

Answer (score 4):

You can create a mock JSONObject with the simple code

```
JSONObject mock = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
```

Then you can easily mock it's methods such as the field getters, to be able to return whatever you want from the JSONObject.

If the problem is that this JSONObject is created in the middle of a long function, you can extract the JSONObject creation to a collaborator and then mock the collaborator.

```
MyClass {
   MyClass(JSONObjectCreator creator) {
      this.creator = creator;
   }
   public void doesSomethingWithJSON(String input) {
      //...
      JSONObject jsonObject = creator.createJSONObject(input);
      //...
   }
}
JSONCreator {
   public JSONObject createJSONObject(String input) {
      return new JSONObject(input);
   }
}
```

In your test you would create a mock JSONObject, and a new MyClass with a mocked JSONObjectCreator.  The mocked JSONObjectCreator would return the mock JSONObject.

Comment: I know I can inject a Factory, but it won't to avoid it if possible. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I've suggested two ways to create mocks.  I am not sure what you want or need your test to do, nor why you want to avoid injecting a factory.

Comment: I don't want to créate a Factory for every framework component I want to create. I just want to inject a mock on constructor call as explained on question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kotlin and [Mockk](https://mockk.io) lib

```
private val json: JSONObject = mockk(relaxed = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way to get the reference of JSONObject in your InjectMock class, Please refer to the below snippet

```
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier;

private final Gson gson = new Gson();

@InjectMocks
private AppleService appleService;

MemberModifier.field(AppleService.class, "gson").set(appleService,gson);
```