# How to "unit-test" json parsing on Android (JSONObject == "null")?

Tags: android, json, unit-testing

I have some problems. I've created JSONParser and need to make a unit tests on it. But, if I'm trying to pass a String object with a copy of valid JSON, every time JSONObject, which is part of my Parser have a value of null.

Here the examples.

JSON I'm assigning to the String:

```
public class JSONParserTest {
    private JSONParser parser;
    private Translations translations;
    private String nounsAndAdjectivesJson = "{\"head\":{},\"def\":[{\"text\":\"house\",\"pos\":\"noun\",\"ts\":\"haʊs\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"дом\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"м\",\"syn\":[{\"text\":\"домик\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"м\"},{\"text\":\"хаус\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"м\"}],\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"home\"},{\"text\":\"cottage\"}],\"ex\":[{\"text\":\"white house\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"белый дом\"}]},{\"text\":\"wooden house\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"деревянный домик\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"помещение\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ср\",\"syn\":[{\"text\":\"здание\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ср\"}],\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"room\"},{\"text\":\"building\"}],\"ex\":[{\"text\":\"house of parliament\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"здание парламента\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"гостиница\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ж\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"hotel\"}]},{\"text\":\"семья\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ж\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"family\"}]},{\"text\":\"хозяйство\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ср\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"farm\"}]},{\"text\":\"театр\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"м\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"theatre\"}]},{\"text\":\"палата\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ж\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"chamber\"}],\"ex\":[{\"text\":\"house of representatives\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"палата представителей\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"жилье\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ср\",\"syn\":[{\"text\":\"жилище\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ср\"}],\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"housing\"}],\"ex\":[{\"text\":\"safe houses\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"безопасное жилье\"}]},{\"text\":\"traditional house\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"традиционное жилище\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"род\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"м\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"kind\"}]},{\"text\":\"рубка\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ж\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"cutting\"}]},{\"text\":\"династия\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ж\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"dynasty\"}]},{\"text\":\"публика\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ж\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"audience\"}]},{\"text\":\"биржа\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"ж\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"market\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"house\",\"pos\":\"adjective\",\"ts\":\"haʊs\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"домашний\",\"pos\":\"прилагательное\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"home\"}],\"ex\":[{\"text\":\"house arrest\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"домашний арест\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"домовый\",\"pos\":\"прилагательное\",\"ex\":[{\"text\":\"house mouse\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"домовая мышь\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"комнатный\",\"pos\":\"прилагательное\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"room\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"house\",\"pos\":\"verb\",\"ts\":\"haʊs\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"расквартировывать\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\"},{\"text\":\"размещаться\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"host\"}]},{\"text\":\"жить\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"live\"}]},{\"text\":\"вмещать\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"accommodate\"}]},{\"text\":\"поселить\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"сов\",\"syn\":[{\"text\":\"приютить\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"сов\"}],\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"settle\"},{\"text\":\"shelter\"}]},{\"text\":\"помещать\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"place\"}]}]}]}";
    private String verbsJson = "{\"head\":{},\"def\":[{\"text\":\"peek\",\"pos\":\"verb\",\"ts\":\"piːk\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"взглянуть\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"сов\",\"syn\":[{\"text\":\"заглянуть\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"сов\"},{\"text\":\"заглядывать\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\"}],\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"glance\"},{\"text\":\"look\"}],\"ex\":[{\"text\":\"peek inside\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"заглянуть внутрь\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"выглянуть\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"сов\",\"syn\":[{\"text\":\"выглядывать\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\"},{\"text\":\"подглядывать\",\"pos\":\"глагол\",\"asp\":\"несов\"}],\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"look\"},{\"text\":\"peep\"}]}]},{\"text\":\"peek\",\"pos\":\"noun\",\"ts\":\"piːk\",\"tr\":[{\"text\":\"быстрый взгляд\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"quick look\"}]},{\"text\":\"взгляд украдкой\",\"pos\":\"существительное\"},{\"text\":\"пик\",\"pos\":\"существительное\",\"gen\":\"м\",\"mean\":[{\"text\":\"peak\"}]}]}]}";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        translations = new Translations();
    }

    @Test
    public void testVerbsOnlyParsing() throws JSONException{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(verbsJson);
        parser = new JSONParser(jsonObject);
        translations = parser.getTranslations();
        Assert.assertNotNull(translations.getVerbs());
    }
}
```

My unit-test of JSONParser

```
@Test
public void testVerbsOnlyParsing() throws JSONException, IOException {
    parser = new JSONParser(verbsJson);
    translations = parser.getTranslations();
    Assert.assertNotNull(translations.getVerbs());
}
```

And a part of JSONParser, which have a problem of getting data from String during the initialization of JSONObject:

```
public class JSONParser {
    private Translations translations;
    public JSONParser(String response) throws JSONException {
        translations = new Translations();
        parseJSON(response);
    }

    private void parseJSON(String response) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response); //object == "null"
        JSONArray arrayOfDefinitions = getArray(object, DEFINITION);
        parseArray(arrayOfDefinitions, TRANSLATIONS);
    }
```

I really don't know what cause the problem (JSONObject object == "null"), could you help me please?

Comment: If you have an exception at runtime, you should always post the full stack trace with your question.

Comment: The answer for your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35675861/3032209

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
testCompile "org.json:json:20140107"
```

This will replace the stubbed Android library with one that works on the desktop.

See this post for a great explanation https://medium.com/@yair.kukielka/android-unit-tests-explained-219b04dc55b5#.qnsgqo7qf