# Using JSONObject#toString in Unit Tests (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, json, unit-testing, tostring

I would like to check if one of my classes deals fine with a JSON object. For that I decided to provide it with a JSONObject using the unit test environment. But it consistently failed to provide the desired results... until I tested the behavior of the **JSONObject in the test method** itself.

This is the code:

```java
    @Test
    public void checkJsonObject() {

        JSONObject obj;
        try {

            obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("front", "cat");
            obj.put("back", "chat");
            obj.put("bucket", 2);

            System.out.println("Object is " + (obj == null ? "" : "not") + " null");
            System.out.println("JSON content is: " + obj.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

These are the obtained results:

```
Object is not null
JSON content is: null
```

Whereas the **expected** result is:

```
Object is not null
JSON content is: {  "front"     : "cat",
                    "back"      : "chat",
                    "bucket"    : 2
                }
```

(or similar).

So, the JSONObject is not null. But the .toString() method returns null.

What am I missing in the code?

In case, it matters, the dependencies of the app contain:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you, guys, in the comments. `testImplementation "org.json:json:20190722"` did work. Maybe someone could provide an answer how to make it work for all cases of this type, so I don't have to look for what's wrong for half a day... Running tests on the phone? Inclusion of a particular android package? How is that done?... Or maybe, at least, do something, so Android Studio provides a warning that some (seemingly) standard class is not implemented in the tests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40960856/1506585

Comment: your code works just fine with me. maybe you have to testimplement json